# Minimum cut in a graph does not change when the weight of all edges is increased by one

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Suppose we have a Graph $G$ in which weight of all edges is $> 1$ (positive). If we increase weight of all edges by one, why does the minimum cut $(S, T)$ of $G$  into two graphs remain the same?

the following graph if we add all edges by one not change the min-cut

[image]

This is a question arise when I read a graph theory book.

Comment: Dear @900sit-upsaday, I take note, so I didn't access to original book. you means in this situation the min cut change?

Comment: Please state the title/author of the book, in case someone else has access to it.

Comment: infact this is a unpublished book, my professor teach it in China university.

Comment: Dear @900sit-upsaday, for example, If each edge weight is increased by 1, the minimum spanning tree doesn’t change

Comment: So, in **this** graph the mincut will not change, since we are always going to cut two of the edges with smallest weights. Was your question just about this particular 5-cycle graph?

Comment: Dear @900sit-upsaday, no, my question, "for a Graph G  in which weight of all edges is > 1  (positive). If we increase weight of all edges by one, Min-Cut (S,T) is remain in two graph or change"

Comment: In that case, my counterexample shows that min-cut can change, since we could have $a,b>1$ there.

Comment: This question is not about computer science, algebraic graph theory, or trees, so I have removed those tags. In particular, please only use "computer science" for questions *about* computer science, not for purely mathematical questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition, [minimum cut](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_cut) is the partition of vertices in two nonempty sets that minimizes the total weight of edges connecting the two parts. Here is an example of how it can change if the weights are all increased by $1$.

Take complete graph $K_n$ with all edges of weight $a$, and attach a new vertex to it by a single edge of weight $b$. The minimum cut will be across the added edge if $b<a(n-1)$, and it will be within $K_n$ if $b>a(n-1)$.

Observe that it is possible to have $b>a(n-1)$ but $b+1<(a+1)(n-1)$; thus, increasing the weights by $1$ can change the position of minimum cut.

Concrete example: $a=2$, $b=11$, $n=6$. Here $b>5a$ but $(b+1)<5(a+1)$.

Comment: would u please see my image in question ?

Comment: I ran into a new question, can we say weight of min-cut is change but structure of min-cut is remain?

Comment: @MounaMokhiab No, the structure changes too. In my example, it changes from cutting off a vertex of $K_n$ (this means cutting $n-1$ edges incident to it) to cutting off the vertex connected by single edge.

Comment: thanks again. so all of it's change.